# would have gone (subjunctive "would have pp" vs. past occasional habit)

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives

> By the time he reached the house, she **would** have gone inside to get his bowl of milk ready for him.

I think this 'would' here means 'past habit' rather than meaning the 'reversed speculation about the past from the perspective of now'

What's the exact usage of 'would' in the sentence above?

Comment: "Would have gone...." signifies that **this action was anticipated or expected to happen prior to his reaching the house.**

Comment: I agree with Sam. This is an [epistemic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality) use of the modal "would".

Comment: If this sentence was about a past occational habit, just "would" be enough. There would be no need for "would+have+gone" structure. So, this usage must be something special like a speculation/guessing about a situation in the past.